# I am getting a windows boot manager while i am installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, troubleshooting

II am trying to install Ubuntu as an OS instead of Windows.
i followed these steps, i downloaded on a flash drive USB using rufus.ie. after that i disabled the security boot. then it restarts and give me a blue screen background with two options for ubuntu and windows. I selected ubuntu and then after this it gives me this error

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might to the cause. To fix the problem :

[image: Error]

Comment: Why is this tagged Windows 7? Windows 7 doesn’t support Secure Boot

Comment: yah sorry, didn't notice that but do u suggest any solution

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You also had tagged this [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] but you don't seem to be using WSL either.  WSL is kind of the *opposite* (in a way) of dual-booting, so I'm going to assume you added that tag in error as well and remove it.  If you really are using WSL, please edit your question to clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you may have had Ubuntu installed before? You most likely did not boot from the flash drive you created. The flash drive does not contain Windows Boot Manager.